# setTimeout method not firing

Tags: javascript, ajax

Based on the following method: http://www.ajaxblender.com/article-sources/jquery/call-settimeout-inside-of-object/index.html

My ajax call only fires once.

```
<body>
     <div id="match-data"></div>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
        jQuery(function($){

            function obj(){
                var duration = 1000;

                var tmpFnc = function(){ exec(); };
                setTimeout(tmpFnc, duration);

                function exec(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "web_service.php",
                        data: {
                            format: 'json'
                        },
                        success: function(data){

                            var resultHTML = ""; 
                            var json = $.parseJSON(data);

                            $.each(json, function(key, val){

                               var $team = json[key].name;
                               var $badge = json[key].crestUrl;
                               var $alt_text = json[key].shortName;

                               resultHTML += "<p>"+$team;   
                               resultHTML += '<img style="width:100px;height:100px;" src="'+$badge+ '" alt="'+$alt_text+'"/></p>';   

                              // console.log(resultHTML);
                            });
                            $("#match-data").append(resultHTML);


                        }
                    });
                }
            };        

            obj = new obj();  

        });
     </script>
</body>
```

where I'm expecting it to repeat every second?

Comment: Could you edit to include what you've tried?  Also it's best to narrow down the code with the issue.

Comment: Mother of God... Look at all those functions inside another function inside another function inside....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```
setInterval(exec, duration);
```

That will call `exec` every 1 second, when `duration` is `1000`.

However, since you're doing an ajax call, it might be better to wait for the server to respond first before you wait a second:

```
success: function(data) {
    // omitted
    setTimeout(exec, duration);
}
```

Note: Your `tmpFnc` function is unnecessary.

Comment: I tidied-up also, was a mess all the nested methods. Thanks.

Comment: @cookie i didn't downvote you, but probably because your question has a lot of noise in it. It could be simpler by removing statements that don't contribute to the problem until you have a very simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Basically change your code like below

```
 setInterval(tmpFnc, duration);
 ....
 obj(); //not obj = new obj();
```